# Is copy initialization identical to copy initialization of a copy?

Tags: c++, initialization, copy-elision, copy-initialization

The following two code segments presents the task of initializing variable `b` as a copy of `a`.  The first code segment initializes the variable using *copy initialization* (initialization using `=`).  Assume class `Apple` is simply defined as an empty class: `class Apple {};`

```
Apple a;
Apple b = a;
```

The second code segment initializes the variable using copy initialization as well.  Though what is copied in the initialization is the copy of `a`.

```
Apple a;
Apple b = Apple(a);
```

When reading this blindly, it seems as if a copy happens at `Apple(a)`, and another at `Apple b = ...`.  In contradiction, overriding the copy constructor of `Apple` to print something on copy shows that only one copy happens during `Apple b = Apple(a)`.

Are the two statements `Apple b = a;` and `Apple b = Apple(a);` identical?  Are there instances where they are not identical?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in concept, for `Apple b = Apple(a);`, a temporary `Apple` is constructed from `a` firstly, then `b` is copy-initialized from the temporary. Because of [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), as the effect `b` is initialized from `a` directly.

> Under the following circumstances, the compilers are required to omit the copy and move construction of class objects, even if the copy/move constructor and the destructor have observable side-effects. The objects are constructed directly into the storage where they would otherwise be copied/moved to. The copy/move constructors need not be present or accessible:
>
> - In the initialization of an object, when the initializer expression is a prvalue of the same class type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the variable type:

This kind of copy elision is guaranteed since C++17, before C++17 it's an optimization. Compiling with pre-C++17 mode and option prohibiting optimization, you might see the difference between the two cases.

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/epCqrU13ZrhYT14u)

Comment: Was this pre-C++17 optimization realized independently between compiler developers?  Or, was there formal documentation stating compiler developers should consider implementing this optimization?

Comment: @TarasPalczynski The standard doesn't require such optimization before C++17, it just *allows* such optimization. While most compilers I know do support it.

Comment: Is there some resource that states in a list which compilers support this optimization pre C++17?  Or is the only realistic way is to just try on each compiler and see what it does?

Comment: @TarasPalczynski I'm afraid I don't know that... You might need to check the document of the compilers, or test with the code.